# Console logging handler is not configured in apache ignite

Tags: ignite, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When starting my apache ignite integrated with spring boot
Getting below errors please help.

> (wrn) Failed to resolve IGNITE_HOME automatically for class codebase [class=class o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils, e=URI is not hierarchical]
> Console logging handler is not configured.

Note: `default-config.xml` (cache configuration) is picked properly

Answer (score 1):

You can always set up `igniteHome` property on `IgniteConfiguration` bean, or actually set `IGNITE_HOME` env var.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following page for logger configuration: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging

You can explicitly configure a logger of your choice to be used for Ignite. If you configure a console appender, then it will be used to print log into console.

Comment: i need to use spring boot logging(logback.xml).Will it be possible to integrate along with ignite and i m not using log4j

Comment: @JayaSri you can configure SLF4J to use logback as a backend and have Ignite log to it.

Comment: @Denis How to use console appender? Its not mentioned in the docs I think.

Comment: @Lokesh you should look in Logback (or whatever logger you use) documentation for this information. This section looks related: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender